# How get items in object which contains in nested array given value

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

How I have some nested array of object, And I tried to get matched items with some value which stored in the nested object in this object and there is have nested array also.

Eg:

my data:

```
const items = [
    {
      name: "A",
      data: {
        title: "B",
        subData: {
           val: "AA", 
           anotherData: {
               subC: [
                   {
                    name: "Data Item", 
                    fruits: ["Apple"]
                   }, 
                   {
                    name: "Data Item 2", 
                    fruits: ["Orange"]
                    }
                   ]
              }
        }
      } 
    },
    {
      name: "A",
      data: {
        title: "B",
        subData: {
           val: "AA", 
           anotherData: {
               subC: [
                   {
                    name: "Data Item", 
                    fruits: ["Apple"]
                   }, 
                   {
                    name: "Data Item 2", 
                    fruits: ["Orange"]
                    }
                   ]
              }
        }
      } 
    }
]
```

Here is my data I have a value of fruit eg: **"Apple"**, and I need to get all items which contain **Apple** fruits array

how to do that with the es6 map or filter function?.

I tried this solution but getting undefined

```
 const v =  items.map((item) => {
        return item;
      }).map((a) => {
        return a.data.subData.anotherData
      }).map((b) => {
      console.log("b", b)
         return b
       }).map((x) => {
      return  x
    }).filter((o) => {
      return o.fruits.contains["Apple"]
    });
```

Comment: Can you, given the provided sample data, also provide an example expected output? What do you want returned when an array containing "apple" is found?

Comment: I want to return the root item from this. soo root items which matched with "Apple" in fruits.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use Array.filter and [Array.some](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some)

We filter items by checking if the subC array contains some data items containing the desired search item.

```js
const items = [ { name: "A", data: { title: "B", subData: { val: "AA", anotherData: { subC: [ { name: "Data Item", fruits: ["Apple"] }, { name: "Data Item 2", fruits: ["Orange"] } ] } } } }, { name: "A", data: { title: "B", subData: { val: "AA", anotherData: { subC: [ { name: "Data Item", fruits: ["Apple"] }, { name: "Data Item 2", fruits: ["Orange"] } ] } } } } ] 

function findItems(searchItem) {
    return items.filter(item => { 
        return item.data.subData.anotherData.subC.some(di => di.fruits.includes(searchItem));
    })
}

console.log("Items containing Apple:", findItems("Apple"))

// Or Oranges
console.log("Items containing Orange:", findItems("Orange"))
```

Comment: It's a very nice approach, but I want to return the root item from this. soo root items which matched with "Apple" in fruits. it's given to me subC items only

Comment: It's a very beautiful solution, you help me a lot. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

Filter the array for an item that has the nested sub-state with a fruits array that includes "apple". This is a case-insensitive search.

```
items.filter((item) =>
  item.data.subData.anotherData.subC.some((el) =>
    el.fruits.some((fruit) => fruit.toLowerCase() === "apple")
  )
);
```

```js
const items = [
  {
    name: "A",
    data: {
      title: "B",
      subData: {
        val: "AA",
        anotherData: {
          subC: [
            {
              name: "Data Item",
              fruits: ["Apple"]
            },
            {
              name: "Data Item 2",
              fruits: ["Orange"]
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    name: "A",
    data: {
      title: "B",
      subData: {
        val: "AA",
        anotherData: {
          subC: [
            {
              name: "Data Item",
              fruits: ["Apple"]
            },
            {
              name: "Data Item 2",
              fruits: ["Orange"]
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  }
];

const result = items.filter((item) =>
  item.data.subData.anotherData.subC.some((el) =>
    el.fruits.some((fruit) => fruit.toLowerCase() === "apple")
  )
);

console.log(result);
```